# Changing UINavigationBar items when traversing the navigation hierarchy

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I am trying to customize the items in the `UINavigationBar` using the following code:

```
    CGSize size = [UIImage imageNamed:kGlobalNavigationBarButtonBackOrange].size;
    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kGlobalNavigationBarButtonBackOrange] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kGlobalNavigationBarButtonBackPressedOrange] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

    UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Detail"];
    [item setLeftBarButtonItem:barButton];
    [item setTitleView:self.navigationItem.titleView];

    [self.navigationBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

However when I run this, the Navigation Bar does not look any different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do should be done from within your `vc` view controller. The whole point is that when a new view controller is pushed onto the stack, it is asked for its navigation item and that's used to update the navigation bar.

In `- viewDidLoad` of your view controller, create the bar button and set it as `self. navigationItem. leftBarButtonItem`.

You don't need to create a new navigation item or push any nav items onto the nav bar. Let the view controller framework do this for you.